# Why am I unable to enable the FlyCam in cutscenes?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have followed all the directions correctly from the page [Mass effect 3 Tweaks Page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#FlyCam).

My mapping key is "K" (without shift).

I did the following:
`( Name="K", Command="ToggleFlyCam" )`

in

```
Bioinput.ini/sfxgame/sfxgamemodedefault
Bioinput.ini/sfxgame/sfxgamemodeflycam
```

and

```
( Name="MouseX", Command="PC_LookX" )
( Name="MouseY", Command="PC_LookY" )
( Name="A", Command="PC_StrafeLeft" )
( Name="W", Command="PC_MoveForward" )
( Name="D", Command="PC_StrafeRight" )
( Name="S", Command="PC_MoveBackward" )
```

in

```
Bioinput.ini/sfxgame/sfxgamemodeconversation
```

I also added `( Name="K", Command="ToggleFlyCam" )` in `Bioinput/sfxgame/sfxgamemodecinematic` as discussed [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:PC_Tweaks_(Mass_Effect_3)#FlyCam_in_Conversations).

FlyCam is working everywhere fine but not in cut scenes.

Comment: Is it meant to work in cut scenes?

Comment: yes man @ChrisF

Answer (score 1):

You should add these lines under 'sfxgamemodebase':

```
(Name="MouseX",Command="Count bXAxis | Axis aMouseX",Control=True)
(Name="MouseY",Command="Count bYAxis | Axis aMouseY",Control=True)
(Name="A", Command="PC_StrafeLeft",Control=True)
(Name="D", Command="PC_StrafeRight",Control=True)
(Name="W", Command="PC_MoveForward",Control=True)
(Name="S", Command="PC_MoveBackward",Control=True)
```

To use the freecam, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move using WASD and Mouse.